# Hyperlink not working correctly

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have two hyperlinks in my excel document.

On Sheet1, in cell A1 I have written the formula, `=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet1'!A1","click")`.

On Sheet1, in cell A2 I have done what I think is the same but using a interactive GUI. Right click in cell A2 => Hyperlink => Place in this document => (Type the cell reference) A2.

I also have written a very short sub so that when I click on these hyperlinks I get a message box.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    MsgBox ActiveCell
End Sub
```

I have placed this macro in Sheet1.

When I click on cell A2 I get a MsgBox with the cell value in. As expected

[image: Cell A2]

However, when I click on cell A1 nothing happens.

Why are these two links behaving differently? How can I make cell A1 behave in the same way as cell A2 whilst still using a formula in the cell?

---

**So Why?**

I have a program that generates a CSV file. For simplicity the structure looks a little like this.

```
f1,f2,compare
f3,f2,compare
```

This means it is easy to overwrite the format.

I then open this file and save it as a `.xlsm`. What I wanted to have is when the compare is clicked it would run a macro. This could be in the form of a button or a hyperlink or anything else as long as it is obviously clickable.

Hence why I was going for the approach of `=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet1'!A1","click")` as it was easy to increment the number after the column and still show it was something that was clearly clickable.

Therefore it would be a quick change to get the CSV file output in a format of

```
f1,f2,"=HYPERLINK(""#'Sheet1'!C1"",""compare"")"
f3,f2,"=HYPERLINK(""#'Sheet1'!C2"",""compare"")"
```

The goal of this is to have something that is as automated as possible as this workbook could have over a thousand row so it is not feasible for me to manually sort out a compare button on each row

---

**Update 2**

When the compare button is clicked, a macro is run. This macro is called `CompareFiles`. It takes the values from the cells on the same row but in columns a and b, passes them into a shell command, and opens a different program that is used to compare the files.

Comment: Sadly only the **Inserted** hyperlink can raise an event; the **formulaic** hyperlink cannot.

Comment: Why the `#`?  Also that's a circular reference.  What are you trying to link to?

Comment: @BruceWayne The cells purposly refer to themselves and I got the # from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27783477/4601149

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Well... That is a shame. Is there a way around it, like calling a macro in the url?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent A bit like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33114213/4601149)? Unfortunately with that specific answer, I keep getting a `Reference is not valid` pop up

Comment: Thanks for the link, didn't know that!  What if you try `=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet1'!"&"A1","click")`?

Comment: @BruceWayne Nothing still I'm afraid

Comment: @Dan So your aim is to exploit an hyperlink's event ? What does follow it? Maybe some other event can be used ?  Or, assuming you cannot avoid using an inserted link, could you loop an insertion ?

Comment: Agreed with @MrDogme - What's your ultimate goal with the hyperlink? I feel like this may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @BruceWayne Sorry for the belated response. I have updated the question to show a use case

Comment: @MrDogme Sorry for the belated response. I have updated the question to show a use case

Comment: So when I click cell `C3`, you want a macro to run?  What is the macro called?  Does [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28728600/4650297) help?  Or [this page](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4422-excel-run-macro-from-hyperlink.html)?

Comment: @BruceWayne I have edited the question again. Basically it will take two file paths from column a and b on the same row, then open these two files in a separated comparison tool using a shell command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is select all the cells that need linking to themselves and use a answer by [Gary's Student](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2474656/garys-student) to do it. The original post can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44206848/4601149)

```
Sub HyperAdder()
    Dim r As Range, s As String
    For Each r In Selection
        If Len(r.Text) = 0 Then
            s = "X"
        Else
            s = r.Text
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=r, Address:="", SubAddress:=r.Parent.Name & "!" & r.Address(0, 0), TextToDisplay:=s
    Next r
End Sub
```

---

If you are using a `.vbs` file like myself, in my case to convert the `.csv` and do a few other things, then you can use something similar to the following.

```
For Each cell In YourSheet.UsedRange.Columns("C:F").Cells
    If Len(cell.Text) > 0 Then
        ConflictsSheet.Hyperlinks.Add cell, "", "'" & cell.Parent.Name & "'" & "!" & cell.Address(0, 0), cell.Text
    End If
Next
```